# After installing Security Rules is there a way to filter out all issues except security related ones?

Tags: security, sonarqube

I'm getting started with sonarqube (Version 3.7.2)  and have installed
the Security Rules [securityrules]  plug-in (version 0.3.2).

After deploying the plugin it seemed to activate OK (see Evidence for Successful Plugin Activation, below).  I re-analyzed my project and then went to the dashboard, but i could not see 
the 'security defects' icon which (according to this document: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Security+Rules+Plugin)  is supposed to appear.

I was planning on using that 'view' to drill into a view of only security related issues. 
My question is:

- is there any other way to do this filtering (besides the security defects widget?)
- is there any reason why that widget would not show up.

I understand the securityrules plugin is deprecated for later versions of sonar, but i'm using an older version which should be compatible.

Evidence for Successful Plugin Activation

after restart the plugin appears in the list of 'Installed Plugins' In the Update Center.

In 'sonar.log' i see this statement:

2014.12.17 07:35:57 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Security Rules / 0.3.2

thanks in advance !
 -chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a quality profile which contains only rules of the security plugin. Then you execute the analysis with that profile.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be very simple. After activating the plug-in I needed to configure the dashboard for the project i am analyzing so the security widget is added.  This page describes the mechanics: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Customizing+Dashboards